# How do I calculate the power of ten of $9^{10^{8.58}}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I was trying to find how many decimal digits the number $9^{10^{8.58}}$ has.

$9^{10^{8.58}} = 10^x$

$\log \space {9^{10^{8.58}}} = x$

$10^{8.58} \space\log \space 9 = x$

$x = 10^{8.55}$

Is this correct?

If I keep raising 9 to the power I iteratively calculate, the final power of ten will be shrinking.

Comment: $\log_{10}(9) \times 10^{8.58} \approx 0.954 \times 10^{8.58}.$  To simplify this *approximation* further, you need to compute the $~\log_{10} (0.954).$

Comment: How did you get $10^{8.55}$ from $\log 9 \cdot 10^{8.58}$?

Comment: @bjcolby15 I multiplied $10^{8.55}$ by $log \space 9$ and then pressed `log` again on the calculator, to get the new power of 10.

Comment: Mathematica gives floor[10^8.58 * log10(9)] as 835361485. I'm not sure what the point of your question is if you can just use a calculator.

Comment: Using my [TI-30XA calculator](https://bkstr.scene7.com/is/image/Bkstr/96898), I get $(\log 9)\cdot 10^{8.58}$ to be $10^{8.55965876 \ldots},$ which rounds to $10^{8.56}$ (not $10^{8.55}).$